# Can I increase the size of a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have some code here, and when the button is pressed, I'm trying to extend the JPanel. However, it remains at the height it was previously. Is there a way to do this or is it fixed on the dimensions it was set when it was created?

```
public class GUITest extends JFrame {

    JPanel jp;
    JButton one;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUITest();
    }

    public GUITest() {
        initWidgets();
    }

    public void initWidgets() {
        setSize(250, 250);
        setTitle("Stretch Panel Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        one = new JButton("Click me!");
        ActionListener extend = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
                    jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,(i+70)));
                }
                //System.out.println(jp.getHeight());
            }
        };
        one.addActionListener(extend);
        add(one, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,70));
        add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels after looking at the javadoc I saw it really respects preferred sizes....bad answer, sorry, already deleted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alternatively, you can call revalidate() on the jpanel after the button click

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
                    jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,(i+70)));
                    **jp.revalidate();**
                }
                //System.out.println(jp.getHeight());
            }
```

to clarify, once you change the dimensions, it has to be redrawn. the thing has been changed, but it hasn't been told to update that change visually

Comment: This works! But any idea how I can get it to sort of 'glide'? I have tried pausing the thread briefly in each iteration but it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: +1 for revalidate(). You can't just pause the thread because that will prevent the GUI from repainting itself. Instead you need to use a Swing Timer to schedule the animations.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `validate()` method in order to do that.
I hope i was able to help!

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`jp.setSize(new Dimension(200,(i+70)));`

instead of  `jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,(i+70)));`

in this code on eachclick the size will be increase by 10 :

```
ActionListener extend = new ActionListener() {
            int count=0;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    count=count+10;
                    jp.setSize(new Dimension(100+count,70+count));  
                System.out.println("in listener");
            }
        };
```

one more thing setPrefferedsize is the default size which is called whenever component re-validates. to change the setPrefferedSize on each click :

```
   count=count+10;
                jp.setSize(new Dimension(100+count,70+count));  
        jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100+count,70+count));
```